# memory leak problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, memory-management

I am trying to check and fix all the leaks in my code/project.I am using two ViewControllers(A ,B)."A" viewController object always available in the memory i am not destroying it.In the app user can switch from A to B and vice versa.B object creates and destroy when user switch to "A"  controller.when destroying the "B" I observed leaks which is shown in the below image [image: Leaks]

**Question:** In the above image we can see all the stack trace is looking disabled formate(not like normal class method indication), so any one please give a clue about what might be these leaks? If any solution to solve these type of leaks? Thanks in advance.

**my B class creation:**

```
B *kbViewer = [[B alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
kbViewer.kbDataSource=nil;
kbViewer.kbDataSource=[kbi getBookDataSource]; 
kbViewer.path = selectedPath; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:kbViewer animated:NO];
[kbViewer release];
```

in the B class there is method in that i am pop the viewcontroller

```
-(IBACtion)bookShelfActionSelected{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

after this my B class dealloc is getting fired.

```
-(void)dealloc{
    //here other than IBOutlets all the components/objects I am relesing
    //more over i am not releasing anywhere my IBOutlets
}
```

Comment: We need to see code to be able to help you. Specifically how you allocate and release the UIViewController.

Comment: Show us viewDidUnload, viewDidLoad, init code, dealloc and .h of view controller b.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I am posting my sample.

Comment: The solution is to Use ARC. Trust me, it's a lot easier to deal with ARC rather than to suffer through manual reference counting, and apple is pushing ARC more and more. I will never go back to manual reference counting after the ease I have had with ARC.

Comment: I am not aware of switching my project to ARC and more over my app is preexisting one.Is any way to migrate for ARC suddenly.

Comment: Why you are making a initWithNibName:nil, why nil? This is not the case anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding autorelease simply delegates the ownership of the object to the autorelease pool. And if there is only the global autorelease pool this is a sort of memory leak. (You continue to allocate memory).

The code to create the B controller is right. From the picture I don't see a B object leak. Maybe the problem is how B allocates some objects?

BTW: ARC simplify the memory management, but it is not a garbage collector, so you need to know what you are doing!